# Efficient groupwise aggregation on Scala collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I often need to do something like

```
coll.groupBy(f(_)).mapValues(_.foldLeft(x)(g(_,_)))
```

What is the best way to achieve the same effect, but avoid explicitly constructing the intermediate collections with `groupBy`?

Comment: @sschaef Can you explain the reason for changing "what is the best way" to "Is it possible and if yes how"? It must be possible (Turing completness) and it is easy to find a klunky way to do it. I also makes the question ungrammatical

Comment: "what is the best way" is bad format for a question, normally it can't be answered definitely. But I agree to the rollback after thinking about the edit again, it didn't make the question better.

Answer (score 4):

You could fold the initial collection over a map holding your intermediate results:

```
def groupFold[A,B,X](as: Iterable[A], f: A => B, init: X, g: (X,A) => X): Map[B,X] = 
  as.foldLeft(Map[B,X]().withDefaultValue(init)){
    case (m,a) => {
      val key = f(a)
      m.updated(key, g(m(key),a))
    }
  }
```

You said collection and I wrote `Iterable`, but you have to think whether order matters in the fold in your question.

If you want efficient code, you will probably use a mutable map as in Rex' answer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you could simplify `m :+ m.get(f(a)).map(g(_,a)).getOrElse(g(init,a))` to `m :+ m.getOrElse(f(a), init).map(g(_,a))`

Comment: Note that although this saves memory, it's actually slower than the original.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do it as a one-liner, so you should be sure you need it before writing something more elaborate like this (written from a somewhat performance-minded view since you asked for "efficient"):

```
final case class Var[A](var value: A) { }
def multifold[A,B,C](xs: Traversable[A])(f: A => B)(zero: C)(g: (C,A) => C) = {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  val m = new java.util.HashMap[B, Var[C]]
  xs.foreach{ x =>
    val v = { 
      val fx = f(x)
      val op = m.get(fx)
      if (op != null) op
      else { val nv = Var(zero); m.put(fx, nv); nv }
    }
    v.value = g(v.value, x)
  }
  m.asScala.mapValues(_.value)
}
```

(Depending on your use case  you may wish to pack into an immutable map instead in the last step.)  Here's an example of it in action:

```
scala> multifold(List("salmon","herring","haddock"))(_(0))(0)(_ + _.length)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Char,Int] = Map(h -> 14, s -> 6)
```

Now, you might notice something weird here: I'm using a Java HashMap.  This is because Java's HashMaps are 2-3x faster than Scala's.  (You can write the equivalent thing with a Scala HashMap, but it doesn't actually make things any faster than your original.)  Consequently, this operation is 2-3x faster than what you posted.  But unless you're under severe memory pressure, creating the transient collections doesn't actually hurt you much.

Comment: Thanks! My main issue is memory. I deal with very large collections. For the iinput collections I can use some kind of lazy or out of core implementation but that does not really help with the intermediate ones.

Comment: If you're concerned about memory, you can look into the trove java collections library, which provides special primitives collections.

Comment: @Rex Kerr is the 3x speed difference in hashmap implementations on insertion, retrieval or both?

Comment: @DanielMahler - It makes a somewhat bigger difference for insertion in my hands, but they're both in the 2-3x range depending on various hard-to-pin-down factors (processor cache, JIT compilation effectiveness, etc.).