# Combine values with same keys in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8

I currently have 2 lists List('a','b','a') and List(45,65,12) with many more elements and elements in 2nd list linked to elements in first list by having a key value relationship. I want combine  elements with same keys by adding their corresponding values and create a map which should look like Map('a'-> 57,'b'->65) as 57 = 45 + 12.

I have currently implemented it as

```
val keys = List('a','b','a')
val values = List(45,65,12)
val finalMap:Map(char:Int) =
  scala.collection.mutable.Map().withDefaultValue(0)
  0 until keys.length map (w => finalMap(keys(w)) += values(w))
```

I feel that there should be a better way(functional way) of creating the desired map than how I am doing it. How could I improve my code and do the same thing in more functional way?

Comment: The answer to this question are appropriate if the collection is very large http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529726/efficient-groupwise-aggregation-on-scala-collections. Scala collections should really provide a `combineByKey` like Apache Spark does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going to +1 Lee's first version, but `mapValues` is a view, and ell always looks like one to me.  Just not to seem petty.

```
scala> (keys zip values) groupBy (_._1) map { case (k,v) => (k, (v map (_._2)).sum) }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(b -> 65, a -> 57)
```

Hey, the answer with fold disappeared.  You can't blink on SO, the action is so fast.

I'm going to +1 Lee's typing speed anyway.

Edit: to explain how `mapValues` is a view:

```
scala> keys.zip(values).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(l => l.map { v =>
     | println("OK mapping")
     | v._2
     | }.sum)
OK mapping
OK mapping
OK mapping
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(b -> 65, a -> 57)

scala> res2('a')   // recomputes
OK mapping
OK mapping
res4: Int = 57
```

Sometimes that is what you want, but often it is surprising. I think there is a [puzzler](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-037) for it.

Comment: @AmigoNico You're asking about "mapValues is a view"? As the scaladoc says, the function isn't applied until you ask for it, so the final map and sum would be incurred on every lookup.

Answer (score 6):

```
val m = keys.zip(values).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(l => l.map(_._2).sum)
```

EDIT: To explain how the code works, `zip` pairs corresponding elements of two input sequences, so

```
keys.zip(values) = List((a, 45), (b, 65), (a, 12))
```

Now you want to group together all the pairs with the same first element. This can be done with `groupBy`:

```
keys.zip(values).groupBy(_._1) = Map((a, List((a, 45), (a, 12))), (b, List((b, 65))))
```

`groupBy` returns a map whose keys are the type being grouped on, and whose values are a list of the elements in the input sequence with the same key.

The keys of this map are the characters in `keys`, and the values are a list of associated pair from `keys` and `values`. Since the keys are the ones you want in the output map, you only need to transform the values from `List[Char, Int]` to `List[Int]`.

You can do this by summing the values from the second element of each pair in the list.

You can extract the values from each pair using `map` e.g.

```
List((a, 45), (a, 12)).map(_._2) = List(45,12)
```

Now you can sum these values using `sum`:

```
List(45, 12).sum = 57
```

You can apply this transform to all the values in the map using `mapValues` to get the result you want.

Comment: Hi @Lee - it's always a good idea to explain your solution so that total n00bs can learn a thing or two from your great idea... :)
ie, don't just post the code - give a brief explanation of why this is better and how it works etc :)

Comment: @TarynEast - Sorry, I was being a bit lazy there. I've added an explanation.

Comment: A couple of minor tweaks:
`(keys,values).zipped.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You were actually on the right track to a reasonably efficient functional solution. If we just switch to an immutable collection and use a fold on a key-value zip, we get:

```
( Map[Char,Int]() /: (keys,values).zipped ) ( (m,kv) =>
  m + ( kv._1 -> ( m.getOrElse( kv._1, 0 ) + kv._2 ) )
)
```

Or you could use `withDefaultValue 0`, as you did, if you want the final map to have that default. Note that `.zipped` is faster than `zip` because it doesn't create an intermediate collection.  And a `groupBy` would create a number of other intermediate collections.  Of course it may not be worth optimizing, and if it is you could do even better than this, but I wanted to show you that your line of thinking wasn't far off the mark.

Comment: How does it work and this syntax is different from what I have seen till now.

Comment: instead of `case (m,kv)` you can write `case (m,(k,v))` and have the ugly underscores magically disappear: `m + ( k -> ( m.getOrElse(k,0) + v ) )`

Comment: How would the complete statemant look like with your change because  `( Map[Char,Int]() /: (keys,values).zipped ) (  (m,(k,v)) =>  m + ( k -> ( m.getOrElse( k, 0 ) + v ) ))` gave me an error.

Comment: Kevin, I'd love for you to be right, but `foldLeft` takes a function with two parameters, so I'm thinking that we can't use a PartialFunction here.  No?

Comment: "this syntax is different" -- actually, it's not really syntax.  `/:` is just another method, also known as `foldLeft`.  [This article](http://nicholassterling.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/an-intuition-about-scalas-operator-foldleft/) may help you understand what it does.  Basically whenever you initialize a mutable variable and update it for each element of a collection, you could do the same thing immutably with a fold.